# Anaconda - I have set up an environment, how do I use it?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, pybrain, conda

I have set up an environment in [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) and installed additional packages in it (mainly [pybrain](http://pybrain.org/)).

How can I access the environment's modules and packages?
Can those be imported from a python script? If so, how?

I searched the documentation but did not find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an environment created with `conda`, you need to activate it.

On Windows:

```
activate myenv_name
```

Other platforms:

```
source activate myenv_name
```

Replace `myenv_name` with name of your environment.

If you don't have such an environment skip this step.

Install `pybrain` with:

```
pip install pybrain
```

Now you can use it.